# `AutoCompleteTextView` is displaying the content only when it has focus

Tags: android

In my android App, `AutoCompleteTextView` is displaying the content only when it has focus, whenever it looses focus it is not displaying the content. However, when I switch back to
`AutoCompleteTextView` it starts displaying it.

Is it possible to make it keep displaying the content?

Comment: Did you check your text color and background of textview